# how to integrate Ldap connection in jhipster

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, jhipster, jhipster-registry

Hi everyone I am new in hipster and I would like to integrate an LDAP connection to authenticate users in my application? I would like if the users connect for the first time pass by the Ldap and we add all his info in local database, then his second authenticator will be in the local database also I would like redirect the users to different pages based on his role;
can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: Spring Boot has LDAP guide. https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

Comment: yes i have test this code alone it work fine  but i wanna integrate it in the jhipster project

Comment: Jhipster is a Spring app, it shouldn't be an issue, You just need to repace jhipster security config to ldap configuration.(not straight i'm afraid)

Comment: how can i add this :https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/